# Tasks with type gradle Kotlin script convert from Groovy (shadow plugin)

Tags: gradle, groovy, build.gradle, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I tried to convert the Groovy script from [shadow plugin's guide](https://imperceptiblethoughts.com/shadow/plugins/#using-shadow-to-package-gradle-plugins)

```
task relocateShadowJar(type: ConfigureShadowRelocation) {
    target = tasks.shadowJar
}
tasks.shadowJar.dependsOn tasks.relocateShadowJar
```

with something like

```
tasks.register("relocateShadowJar") {
    com.github.jengelman.gradle.plugins.shadow.tasks.ConfigureShadowRelocation(tasks.shadowJar)
}
```

But it says "too many argument" at `tasks.shadowJar`. I assumed it needs to be initialized or something like that? How do I convert this? please help me, thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, found what I want

```
task<ConfigureShadowRelocation>("relocateShadowJar") {
    target = tasks.shadowJar.get()
}

tasks.shadowJar.get().dependsOn(tasks.getByName("relocateShadowJar"))
```